# Indian tourist needs money in Atlanta

Tags: united-states, india, cash, transfer

My Indian friend visiting Atlanta needs money. He has no US Id. How can he get money from a US bank account of my US resident friend in New York

Comment: Does he have an Indian passport in his possession?

Comment: Have you _talked_ to the Indian friend in question and know for sure that he needs money? I have received numerous "requests" from people that I know with a sob story such as "I am traveling and in XYZ city. My pocket has been picked and I've lost all my cash and all my IDs. Can you send me some money....?" and in all cases it has been a fraud -- said friend's e-mail addressbook has been compromised and a hacker has been sending this message to lots of people while friend goes about his real business blissfully unaware of what e-mails are being sent out in his name. So, be careful....

Answer (score 2):

He cannot get money from someone else account.

Your US resident friend in New York can send money to your Indian friend in Atlanta via Western Union which has presence in almost every corner of the US. Most definitely in the city of Atlanta. Your Indian friend can receive the Western Union transfer, in cash, within minutes after the friend in New York sends it. Here's the site [for location search](http://locations.westernunion.com/?iframe=false). The sender doesn't need to go anywhere, can send [online](https://www.westernunion.com/us/en/send-money-online.html), so your New York friend doesn't even need to waste much time. In fact - you don't need to bother your friend in New York, you can send it online yourself (assuming you're American/have US bank account).

In order to receive the money, your Indian friend will obviously need a proper identification (i.e.: passport).

Comment: Just to reinforce the point, _please_ read and heed @DilipSarwate's warning above. International fund transfer is a major target for scams of various sorts. Be _very_ sure who you are transferring money to, that their request is legitimate, and that it's really them.